# Using react context with react hooks in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context, react-hooks

Code below demonstrates how I'm trying to implement react's context with react hooks, idea here is that I will be able to easily access context from any child component like this

```
const {authState, authActions} = useContext(AuthCtx);
```

To begin with I create a file that exports context and provider.

```
import * as React from 'react';

const { createContext, useState } = React;

const initialState = {
  email: '',
  password: ''
};

const AuthCtx = createContext(initialState);

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  function setEmail(email: string) {
    setState({...state, email});
  }

  function setPassword(password: string) {
    setState({...state, password}); 
  }

  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const actions = {
    setEmail,
    setPassword
  };

  return (
    <AuthCtx.Provider value={{ authState: state, authActions: actions }}>
      {children}
    </AuthCtx.Provider>
  );
}

export default AuthCtx;
```

This works, but I get error below in `value` of provider, probably because I add actions in, hence the question, is there a way for me to keep everything typed and still be able to export context and provider?

I beliebe I also can't place `createContext` into my main function since it will re-create it all the time?

> [ts] Type '{ authState: { email: string; password: string; };
>   authActions: { setEmail: (email: string) => void; setPassword:
>   (password: string) => void; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ email:
>   string; password: string; }'.   Object literal may only specify known
>   properties, and 'authState' does not exist in type '{ email: string;
>   password: string; }'. [2322] index.d.ts(266, 9): The expected type
>   comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type
>   'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<{ email: string; password:
>   string; }>' (property) authState: {
>       email: string;
>       password: string; }

Comment: Where are you typing your context

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri by default it inherits it from `createContext(initialState)` issue is that creation is outside of function, hence I can't type actions I think. And I need those actions inside my function component as they update state. If I move context inside the function, I can easily type actions, but no longer export context and I think there will be complications since react function components are re-ran on each render

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While creating Context, you are providing an initial value to it. Provide it in the same format as you expect it to be for the Provider like:

```
const initialState = {
  authState : { 
      email: '',
      password: ''
  },
  authActions = {
    setEmail: () => {},
    setPassword: () => {}
  };
};

const AuthCtx = createContext(initialState);
```

Also, you don't even need the initialState since its only passed to Consumer, if you don't have a Provider higher up in the hierarchy for the Consumer.

Comment: when i use usestate in my context i see this error .Type 'Dispatch<any>' is not assignable to type '() => void

Answer (score 33):

Answer above works, because strict rules of checking of types disabled.
Example for context with strict rules:

```
import { createContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction, useState } from 'react';
import { Theme } from '@styles/enums';
import { Language } from '@common/enums';

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

type Context = {
  appLang: string;
  appTheme: string;
  setContext: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Context>>;
};

const initialContext: Context = {
  appLang: Language.EN,
  appTheme: Theme.DEFAULT,
  setContext: (): void => {
    throw new Error('setContext function must be overridden');
  },
};

const AppContext = createContext<Context>(initialContext);

const AppContextProvider = ({ children }: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const [contextState, setContext] = useState<Context>(initialContext);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ ...contextState, setContext }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { AppContext, AppContextProvider };
```

It works for me. `Theme` and `Language` it just enums, like this:

```
export enum Theme {
  DEFAULT = 'DEFAULT',
  BLACK = 'BLACK',
}
```

And I send Error function in `setContext` inner `initialContext` for throwing error if programmer doesn't define `setContext` in `Provider`. You can just use

`setContext: (): void => {}`

Good luck!

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, thank you.