# Type 'unknown[]' is missing the following properties from type 'InitialState'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context, use-reducer

Trying to work out how to pass types to **value**?

```
<Context.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>{children} 
</Context.Provider>
```

> Type 'unknown[]' is missing the following properties from type 'InitialState': navigateTo, user, avatar, dashBoardSelectedMenuItemts(2739)
> index.d.ts(338, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps'
> (JSX attribute) React.ProviderProps.value: InitialState

```
import React, { createContext } from "react";
import Reducer from "./reducer";

interface InitialState {
  navigateTo: string;
  user: string;
  avatar: string;
  dashBoardSelectedMenuItem: string;
}

const initialState: InitialState = {
  navigateTo: "dashboard",
  user: null,
  avatar: null,
  dashBoardSelectedMenuItem: "dashboard",
};
export const Context = createContext<InitialState>(initialState);

const Store = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer<any>(Reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>{children}</Context.Provider>
  );
};

export default Store;
```

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import React, { createContext } from "react";
import Reducer from "./reducer";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

interface InitialState {
  navigateTo: string;
  user: string | null;
  avatar: string | null;
  dashBoardSelectedMenuItem: string;
}

const initialState: InitialState = {
  navigateTo: "dashboard",
  user: null,
  avatar: null,
  dashBoardSelectedMenuItem: "dashboard"
};

export const Context = createContext<[InitialState, React.Dispatch<any>]>([
  initialState,
  () => {}
]);

const Store = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(Reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>{children}</Context.Provider>
  );
};

export default Store;
```

In your reducer add the type information for the state like below

```
export const Reducer = (state: InitialState, action:any): InitialState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: you're close error has now moved to'state' instead of value... Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'InitialState': navigateTo, user, avatar, dashBoardSelectedMenuItem

Comment: works with comment from @shankar bellow removed any from usereducer

Comment: accepting your answer as was closest did not need the reducer code, pls credit @shankar upadhyay below.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to help you.

Here as you have defined the type os user and avatar in Initial state as string you should pass string only as value.

Perhaps **you are passing null instead of an empty string ""** could solve the type problem.

typeof null is Object.

`const initialState: InitialState = { navigateTo: "dashboard", user: "", avatar: "", dashBoardSelectedMenuItem: "dashboard", };`

You may visit this link for similar problem [Using react context with react hooks in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53335907/using-react-context-with-react-hooks-in-typescript)

Comment: Hi,  after changing the values to empty strings, value is still complaining type unknown[] is missing the ... , same as before , thanks for trying.

Comment: Hi, same after trying value={[{{initialState:state}, dispatch]}>

Comment: createContext<[InitialState, React.Dispatch<any>]> can you try after removing the array if it doesn't have a purpose createContext<InitialState, React.Dispatch<any>>

Comment: that works in combo with @Amila Senadheera answer above